# Bootstrap Carousel slideshow (fixed height but keep image center top)

Tags: bootstrap-4

I have the below code:

```
    <div id="carouselExampleSlidesOnly" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
        <img src="assets/slideshowimage.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img src="assets/slideshowimage.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

(image used is 1900 X 305 px)

The code works but I need to keep the image height the same when resized. At the moment when you re-size the screen the image height is lowered as the image is resized.

Ideally I need it to act like a background image (with 'cover' and 'center top') so the image height stays the same and the image simply gets cropped on the left and right as the browsers resized.

Using bootstrap 4.5

I tried setting the carousel-item with a background image but that didn't seem to work.

Can someone point me in the right direction please?

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`d-block w-100` makes the image be and therefor resize 100%. You will have to overwrite the css to make it happen.

Note that you should prefer to overwrite it in your own `app.css` file not in the bootstrap one.

See docu: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/sizing/

E.g.
**app.css**

```
.d-block w-100 {

    width: 10vw;

}
```